# containerd.io vs docker-ce-cli vs docker-ce: what are the differences and what does each package do?

Tags: docker, containers

I am trying to install docker on my laptop and I find that there are three packages from [the repo](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/pool/stable/amd64/):

- containerd.io
- docker-ce-cli
- docker-ce

Can anyone explain to me in simple words what the differences are among these packages, what each one of them does, and what part of the docker architecture each corresponds to? Also, can they work independently on each other?

Comment: This should be [clarified in Docker's documentation](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/12366).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**containerd.io** : daemon [containerd](https://containerd.io). It [works](https://containerd.io/docs/getting-started/) independently on the docker packages, and it is required by the docker packages.

> containerd is available as a daemon for Linux and Windows. It manages the complete container lifecycle of its host system, from image transfer and storage to container execution and supervision to low-level storage to network attachments and beyond.

**docker-ce-cli** : command line interface for docker engine, community edition

**docker-ce** :  [docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) engine, community edition. Requires docker-ce-cli.